# Share webpage with social network

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a web page and I wish to share a link or tell a friend about this page. So,when I click the share link then the System shall execute AddThis Wigit (fb, twitter, google, myspace, etc).

What is the C# code that execute this implementation?

I am using MVC.

Comment: What have you tried so far to tackle this problem? Did you encounter some specific problems trying to implement this? You shouldn't expect anyone on StackOverflow writing code for you. Another possibility of course is to hire a developer.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com) site.  They will give you some code to put in your HTML that will let the end user send the current page to all sorts of social media sites.