# Share a link to social network by using add this widget

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a web page and I wish to share a link or tell a friend about this page. So,when I click the share link then the System shall execute AddThis Wigit (fb, twitter, google, myspace, etc).

What is the C# code that execute this implementation?

I am using MVC.

Comment: Google around, there are dozens of sharing widgets you can use. Unless you'd like to write your own, in that case you should begin by looking at each services API's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [share webpage with social network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475975/share-webpage-with-social-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the widgets use plain javascript and html. You don't need to do anything server-side.

I found a website where you can generate a widget: http://www.sharepost.com/